# Feeding PyQtGraph bar chart with 2D-Array

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, bar-chart, pyqtgraph

I have this 2D-Array:

```
[[200, 200, 215], [161, 162, 172], [72, 45, 31], [116, 75, 33], [182, 182, 195], [103, 63, 26], [151, 152, 156], [211, 211, 228], [190, 191, 204], [98, 75, 49], [93, 51, 23], [135, 135, 135], [117, 107, 84], [163, 99, 35], [172, 173, 184], [172, 173, 184]]
```

I want to plot something like a histogram.
These are RGB values.

What I want to do is to plot the quantity of each Subarray (in this case 1) on X-Axis and the pairs printed as labels on Y-Axis. Is it possible to feed my PyQtGraph like that and colorize the bars with the corresponding colors?

Here is an example with Ruby and ChartJS:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove bottom axis tick labels, then add each bar as a pg.InfiniteLine object with appropriate width.

Changing tick labels of y-axis to r,g,b values can be achieved by using AxisItem.setTicks(ticks) method.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

class ColorBarPlot(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ColorBarPlot, self).__init__()
        self.p1 = pg.PlotItem() 
        self.addItem(self.p1)
        self.p1.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(showValues=False)

    def displayColors(self, colors):
        
        self.p1.clear()
        ticks = []
        for i, color in enumerate(colors):
            line = pg.InfiniteLine(
                pos=i+1, # y value of the line 
                angle=0, # horizontal, 90 is vertical 
                pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor(color[0], color[1], color[2]), width=15) # Set color
            )
            self.p1.addItem(line)
            ticks.append((i+1, '{},{},{}'.format(color[0], color[1], color[2])))
        self.p1.getAxis('left').setTicks([ticks])



if __name__ == "__main__":

    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication([])
    win = QMainWindow()
    plot = ColorBarPlot()
    win.setCentralWidget(plot)
    plot.displayColors([[200, 200, 215], [161, 162, 172], [72, 45, 31], [116, 75, 33], [182, 182, 195], [103, 63, 26], [151, 152, 156], [211, 211, 228], [190, 191, 204], [98, 75, 49], [93, 51, 23], [135, 135, 135], [117, 107, 84], [163, 99, 35], [172, 173, 184], [172, 173, 184]])
    win.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(Qt.QtCore, "PYQT_VERSION"):
        QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OedET.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).